# Selenium for Flash? (or other record/playback tool for authoring tests)

Tags: flash, selenium

is there something like Selenium for Flash?

Or any other record/playback tool for authoring tests for Flash?

Many thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have never used it but have heard a lot of good things about [FlexMonkium](http://flexmonkey.org/wordpress/2010/02/22/flexmonkium-flexmonkeyselenium-bridge/) to do Selenium and Flash together.

Answer (score 2):

There is no inbuilt support for Flash but you can run it via Selenium RC with an extension. Refer [Writing and running functional tests for Flash with Selenium RC](http://www.adobe.com/devnet/flash/articles/flash_selenium.html) 
 and [flash-selenium](http://code.google.com/p/flash-selenium/).

There are some tools that automate Flash testing outside of Selenium e.g. [AutomatedQA’s TestComplete](http://www.automatedqa.com/products/testcomplete/testing-flash-apps/) .

Answer (score 1):

Outside of Selenium, we evaluated a tool called Eggplant, which seemed to fare well with Flash. Unfortunately, the cost was prohibitive.